# What happens to an Inkmoth Nexus that has had Tezzeret, Agent of Bolas' -1 ability used on it?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

From my initial expectations I'd expect otherwise, but I was recently told at a tournament that an activated [Inkmoth Nexus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=213731) that had been the target of [Tezzeret, Agent of Bolas](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=214065)' -1 ability ("Target artifact becomes a 5/5 artifact creature.") would cease being a vanilla 5/5 artifact at the end of the turn when [Inkmoth Nexus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=213731)' ability ends. I was planning on using Revoke Existence, but my plans were quashed.

Was this correct? Without looking at layers or anything, I'd assume appears [Tezzeret, Agent of Bolas](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=214065)' ability (which is persistent) would remain active after Inkmoth Nexus' ends, and that on the next turn it would remain a vanilla 5/5 artifact creature.

Comment: I would agree with you, and I don't see anything in the rulings for either card that suggests otherwise. But I don't have an authoritative source to back me up here.

Comment: Sounds similar to the confusion around the good old Jade Statue...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whoever gave you the ruling was mistaken.

[According to level 4 judge Chris Richter](http://blogs.magicjudges.org/rulestips/2011/02/how-inkmoth-nexus-and-tezzeret-agent-of-bolas-interact/), **the Inkmoth Nexus will remain a 5/5 artifact creature land but will lose flying, infect, and its Blinkmoth subtype after the turn ends.**

Some more details on what happens afterward:

> When the turn ends, the animation effect from the Inkmoth Nexus will
>   end. When this happens, the Nexus will be become a 5/5 artifact
>   creature land. This Nexus will still have the normal abilities of an
>   Inkmoth Nexus, the mana ability and the ‘animation’ activated ability,
>   as well. But this permanent will not have flying or infect at this
>   point. This is because Inkmoth Nexus’ animation ability has a duration
>   that lasts until the end of turn, while the animation effect from
>   Tezzeret’s ability does not. The animation effect from Tezzeret’s
>   ability will last as long as that permanent remains in play. If no
>   other effects are applied, then this Nexus will look like this (a 5/5
>   artifact creature land with Nexus abilities) for the rest of the game
>   or as long as this Nexus remains in play.
>
> However, you may just want to use additional animation effects on this
>   Nexus for strategic reasons. If the Inkmoth Nexus’ animation activated
>   ability resolves again, then this permanent will become an 1/1
>   artifact creature land with both flying and infect. It is a 1/1
>   creature again for the same reason as why it became a 5/5 earlier, the
>   power and toughness setting portion of the Nexus’ effect is applied in
>   timestamp order and overrides Tezzeret’s effect that makes it a 5/5.
>   And, just as earlier, you can use Tezzeret’s ability again as well.
>   Doing so will make this permanent into a 5/5 creature with both flying
>   and infect. Then, as before, at the end of turn when the Inkmoth
>   animation effect wears off it will become a 5/5 artifact creature
>   land.